# C - Elegant way to synchronise multiple children with semaphores

Tags: c, ipc

I would like to have n children each printing a different letter to the screen synchronously with the help of semaphores. I did it with one child plus the parent and two semaphores but I don't really see an elegant way to generalise to n children.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union semun {
    int val ;
    struct semid_ds * buf ;
    unsigned short * array ;
    struct seminfo * __buf ;
} ;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int idsem;
    struct sembuf moins1sem1 [ 1 ] = { { 0, -1, 0 } } ;
    struct sembuf plus1sem1 [ 1 ] = { { 0, 1, 0 } } ;
    struct sembuf moins1sem2 [ 1 ] = { { 1, -1, 0 } } ;
    struct sembuf plus1sem2 [ 1 ] = { { 1, 1, 0 } } ;
    // key_t key = ftok("/etc/passwd",71); 
    // perror("Key");
    idsem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 4, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL| 0600); //IPC_CREATE creates key if doesn't exist an EXCL fails if key exists
    //key is a "random" identifier for the sem and 1 is the nuber of sems we want to create 
    //Since we do not need to share the semaphore out of this process and its sons we can not use a key and instead provide the IPC_Private parameter
    perror("idsem");
    if(idsem == -1){
        semget(IPC_PRIVATE,4,0); //If it didn't work w/ flags try w/o
        perror("idsem2");
    }
    else{
        union semun semopts;
        semopts.val = 1; // We create an object to interact with the sem trough semctl
        semctl(idsem,0,SETVAL,semopts);//we set the value (SETVAL) of the first (0) sem in the group of semaphore of id idsem to the value field of semopts
        semopts.val = 0;
        semctl(idsem,1,SETVAL,semopts);
    }
    switch (fork())
    {
    case 0:
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            semop(idsem,moins1sem1,1);
            fprintf(stderr,"Le fils dit A\n");
            semop(idsem,plus1sem2,1);
        }
        break;
    
    default:
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            semop(idsem,moins1sem2,1);
            fprintf(stderr,"Le pere dit B\n");
            semop(idsem,plus1sem1,1);
        }
        break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The idea would be to have a way to generate n sembuf AND to have a function to apply only the n-th operation to a given semaphore

I have tried to define all the operations in an array

```
struct sembuf oparray [ 4 ] = {{ 0, -1, 0 },{ 0, 1, 0 },{ 1, -1, 0 },{ 1, 1, 0 }} ;
```

And to apply the nth operation with

```
semop(idsem,oparray,n);
```

But it applies every operation up to n instead.

Comment: `semop(idsem,oparray,n);` -> `semop(idsem,&oparray[n],1);` ?

Comment: What does *elegant* mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> semop(idsem,oparray,n);
> ```
>
> [...] applies every operation up to n instead [of just the n<sup>th</sup>].

Well yes, that's exactly what `semop()` is documented to do.  To apply just the operation at index `n`, use

```
semop(idsem, oparray + n, 1);
```

or, equivalently,

```
semop(idsem, &oparray[n], 1);
```

Remember also that C indexes start at zero, so the index of the n<sup>th</sup> operation is `n - 1`.